# How to map entity framework model to columns dynamically?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

We are working with a third-party application that allows users to create their own tables with different columns.  Each table follows the format "T{ID}" (T12, T23, etc.).

I've used the following code to access appropriate table:

```
public class RecordDataContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
  public RecordDataContext(string nameOrConnectionString, string tableName)
    : base(nameOrConnectionString)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
      throw new ArgumentNullException("tableName");
    TableName = tableName;
  }

  public string TableName { get; private set; }

  public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
      .ToTable(TableName);
  }
}
```

Each table has certain columns that are the same (ID, CreateDateTime, ModifyDateTime, etc.).  They also allow users to add their own columns, the user friendly column headers are stored in some other table and the columns in the data table follow this format "Index{ID}" (Index20, Index35, etc.).

Using Entity Framework I would like to be able to pull in the data into a POCO model like this where the data from the Index columns are stored in the Data property:

```
public class Record
{
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
  public DateTime ModifyDateTime { get; set; }
  public IDictionary<int, string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

If this is not possible, are there other ways to retrieve the Index columns without making a separate SQL request?

Comment: I'd question the use of EF to manage these tables - I think you're in for a world of pain.

Comment: I've been toying with the same question.  I was wondering if it was possible.  I'm using EF extensively for the rest of the data in the database (50+ tables).  This is just the last set of information I need to access.

Comment: What are you going with the data? What is it for?

Comment: All the EF models and data access code is located in a data access library which may be used by a number of applications.  Currently the only use will be a REST web service which will be exposing the data.  In the web service the data access layer objects are converted to domain objects containing only the required information.  These objects are then serialized to JSON/XML.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I'm facing the same type of task.

Comment: I haven't found a solution using EF.

I am using straight ADO.Net for accessing these 2 types of tables.